# SharePoint 2010 Check Permission shows "None" for Users added through AD Security Groups

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I am using SharePoint 2010 and AD as well.

I have added some users in AD and then I add them to Group called "TestingUsers" in AD, this is group has Group scope **Global** and Group type **Security**, in Sharepoint this group holds only **"Read"** permission,

But when i add user through AD and check permission in SharePoint it shows **"None"** instead of showing **"Read"** and 
moreover this the same user can log into site with credentials as well

pls help me ....

Answer (score 0):

http://blogs.technet.com/b/yashgoel-msft/archive/2012/04/13/check-permissions-showing-quot-none-quot-for-users-added-through-ad-groups-in-sharepoint-2010.aspx

When you try to do checkpermissions for a user added on the
site through AD group you get “none” even though group has permissions on the
site and user also doesn’t have any issue in logging into the site. It’s just
that the check permission doesn’t work for the group and the user.

Resolution:

Take a ULS while doing check permissions and if you see the
following entry

04/02/2012
17:27:49.89        w3wp.exe
(0x169C)        0x0974        SharePoint
Foundation        General        7fdb        Unexpected        AuthZInitializeContextFromSid
failed!        ddd8bfd7-3a2d-4b94-8249-0e22f057a52f

This comes if the farm account doesn’t have permissions to
read the TGGAU attribute of the group or the user ID. To resolve this login to
your Active Directory

AD  users
and groups àview
à check advance features

Right click on the SP farm account à member of à add à windows authorization
access control à
click ok